WireMock on Android: empty list of received requests
I'm trying to integrate WireMock to my Android autotests based on JUnit/Espresso/Kaspresso
I don't need to mock request, I'd like just to verify outgoing requests
build.gradle:
androidTestImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.35.1"

test class:
val wireMockRule: WireMockRule = WireMockRule(8888)

@get:Rule
open val ruleChain: RuleChain = RuleChain
    .outerRule(grantPermissionRule)
    .around(wireMockRule)
    .around(activityRule)

@Test
fun testWiremock() {
    val url = "http://google.com"
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    assertNotNull("just to make sure there is a valid response for this simple request", response.body!!.string())

    verify(anyRequestedFor(UrlPattern.ANY))
}

result:
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: Expected at least one request matching: {
"method" : "ANY"
}
Requests received: [ ]

I'm not using newest version of WireMock due to this issue.
also tried on different emulators (API 26 and 34) and real device on Android 13
looks like I forgot something but can't understand what is it. please help

If your app is using OkHttp (judging by the code you tried implementing) you don't need WireMock at all! You can create a custom Interceptor and register it on your OkHttp application instance and capture requests that you can validate later. You can check out this old implementation I've done that I haven't used in a while - you can of course tailor it to your needs but it can get you started
    private val capturedRequests = mutableListOf<CapturedRequest>()

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()

        val url = request.url.toString()
        val queryParams = extractQueryParams(request.url)
        val method = request.method
        val headers = request.headers.names().associateWith { request.header(it)!! }
        val requestBody = request.body
        val buffer = Buffer()
        requestBody?.writeTo(buffer)
        val body = if (requestBody != null) buffer.readUtf8() else null

        capturedRequests.add(CapturedRequest(url, queryParams, method, headers, body))

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

    private fun extractQueryParams(url: HttpUrl): Map<String, String> {
        val queryParamNames = url.queryParameterNames
        val queryParamsMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

        queryParamNames.forEach { name ->
            val value = url.queryParameter(name) // Retrieves the first value for the name
            if (value != null) {
                queryParamsMap[name] = value
            }
        }

        return queryParamsMap.toMap()
    }

    fun hasRequestWithPath(path: String) {
        capturedRequests.forEach { request ->
            if (request.url.contains(path)) {
                return
            }
        }
        throw Exception("There is no request containing `$path` in the list of captured requests")
    }

    fun getRequestWithPath(path: String): CapturedRequest? {
        capturedRequests.forEach { request ->
            if (request.url.contains(path)) {
                return request
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    fun getCapturedRequests(): List<CapturedRequest> {
        return capturedRequests
    }

    fun clearCapturedRequests() {
        capturedRequests.clear()
    }
}

You can then add some kind of configurator in the application code that allows you to set the instance of the interceptor from the Espresso tests like:
@TestOnly
object OkHttpClientTestConfigurator {
    var espressoInterceptor: Interceptor? = null
}

And then conditionally apply it in the OkHttp client builder like
OkHttpClientTestConfigurator.espressoInterceptor?.let {
   okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(it)
}

